# task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString() is not working/accepted

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Please check the code i am getting an error at getDownloadUrl() method. As it is not being accepted by the firebase. I am a beginner at this, so can anyone please suggest the changes i have to make in this code.

This snippet is basically focused on getting the image url from the storage and add it in the database section in firebase. But the getDownloadUrl is not working, please suggest the changes in the snippet to make it happen.

```
            StorageReference filePath = userProfileImagesReference.child(currentUserID + ".jpg");

            filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Profile Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        //error here
                        final String downloadURL = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                        rootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID).child("image")
                                .setValue(downloadURL)
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                                        {
                                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Image Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            String errorMSG = task.getException().toString();
                                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error: "+errorMSG, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        String error = task.getException().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error: "+error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: You're not using the API correctly.  getDownloadUrl returns a Task that gives you the URL asynchronously. I suggest reviewing the documentation.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url

Comment: Could you please add the exception you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to get it directly from storageReference , so do as following :

`Uri downloadUrl =  filePath.getDownloadUrl();`

Comment: That won't work either.

Comment: did you log  the downloadUrl , are you getting null value ?

Comment: it worked for me because i m working on a project with firebase and its components too

Comment: Trust me, it won't work.  You will get a string, but it won't be a download URL string.

Comment: Trust me it does work and here is my code for you https://pastebin.com/dpYaFwcp , and here a sample from real time database where i save the urls , and here is the sample https://imgur.com/a/PZqqLPB , it is working fine

Comment: getDownloadUrl does not return a Uri type in recent versions of the SDK.

Comment: Yeah i understand , he has to make callback and gets the Uri , in my case i use coroutines so await() , did the job